# VBA code to call a picture as a result of an IF Formula

Tags: image, excel, if-statement, shapes, vba

I have a form on Sheet 1 with multiple cells, (B7:L7, B11:L11, and B13:L13) and 3-4 different pictures on a separate sheet (Sheet 2). I'm trying to have a different picture called for each of those cells depending on their value (i.e., if the cells =2, they should show one of the pictures from the other sheet, if the cells =3, they should show a different picture, etc.).

I've tried this 100 different ways and keep striking out so any input would be greatly appreciated!!

Edit:Including Code- 
Like I said, I've done this about a 100 different ways. This is my most recent attempt. While probably way more clunky than necessary, it works great for one cell, I'm just not sure how to edit it to make it work for the entire range (other than copy and pasting for each cell individually). I'd also like to add in something to center it in the cell, but haven't had luck with that either.

```
Sub InsertPicture()
Dim PicCell As Range

Set PicCell = Range("B7")

If PicCell = 2 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture2")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B7").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Paste
ElseIf PicCell = 3 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture3")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B7").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Paste
ElseIf PicCell = 4 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture4")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B7").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Paste
ElseIf PicCell = 5 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture5")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B7").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Paste
ElseIf PicCell = 6 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture6")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B7").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Paste
Else: MsgBox ("No picture at this time")
End If
```

Comment: Please include your sample code and highlight the problematic part. Best regards,

Comment: consider to add code, so we can help you much easier

Comment: Just added code! I wasn't sure what to add since I've had so many attempts at this. I've now included the most recent version.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "For a whole range"?  Right now everything is in B7, how would this change... what is the logic?

Comment: I guess that is my question. I'm trying to figure out how to re-write this so that it will work on B7:L7, B11:L11, and B13:L13 instead of just B7.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this and see if we're getting close to what you're looking for.

My Sheet1 looks like this:
[image]

Sheet2 just has the images like this:
[image]

---

**Code:** *(simplified and improved but no error checking)*

```
Sub InsertPicture()
    Dim PicSht As Worksheet
    Set PicSht = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In mySheet.Range("B7:L7")
        Select Case cell
            Case 2 To 6
                PicSht.Shapes("Picture" & cell.Value).Copy
                cell.Select
                mySheet.Pictures.Paste

            Case Else
                MsgBox ("No picture at this time")
        End Select
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

Results on Sheet1:

[image]